# How do I set a custom ETag value in a Rails controller response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, etag, actioncontroller

For one controller (only), I'd like to use an ETag value generated outside of rails caching logic, and manage 304-vs-200 responses myself.  It seems that nothing I do to set the ETag header works:

```
response.etag = myEtag
headers['ETag'] = myEtag
render :text => myText, :etag => myEtag
```

Rails always uses its own version.

I know I could disable caching app-wide, but I don't want that - just want to override it in the responses for one `ActionController` subclass.

Comment: you can try "fresh" read more here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832035/rails-etags-vs-page-caching-file-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fresh_when`, etc. didn't quite suit my needs - in my case the solution was to refuse caching via

```
def caching_allowed?
  false
end
```

then set *just* the `headers['ETag']` member on my response - setting any of the `.etag` options seems to cause Rails to MD5 All The Things.

Comment: Question, where do you put that method?

Comment: This was forever ago, but as I recall I was overriding the method in ActionController: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActionController/Caching.html#method-i-caching_allowed-3F

Answer (score -1):

Also if you would like to overwrite it directly, you can set the etag value like below:

```
headers['ETag'] = 'xxxxxx'
```

Code reference from Rack
(**rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/etag.rb**)

```
if etag_status?(status) && etag_body?(body) && !skip_caching?(headers)
    original_body = body
    digest, new_body = digest_body(body)
    body = Rack::BodyProxy.new(new_body) do
        original_body.close if original_body.respond_to?(:close)
    end
    headers[ETAG_STRING] = %(W/"#{digest}") if digest
end

private

def skip_caching?(headers)
    (headers[CACHE_CONTROL] && headers[CACHE_CONTROL].include?('no-cache')) ||
      headers.key?(ETAG_STRING) || headers.key?('Last-Modified')
end
```

Comment: Please notice that this is one of the methods mentioned in the original question, and as _part_ of the answer. What's new/different here?